# Loop stop when adding new index [php-laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

Now i have collection i want to put in array 2D when condition executing but when add new array the execute stop.

briefly, i want to add categories to lines based on condition i hope the problem to be solving

Comment: post your code to we can help

Comment: in first answer